# Undefined object from my product page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

This is my constructor into product-details.ts

```js
product: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {


    this.product = this.navParams.get("product");
    console.log(this.product);
    
  }
```

This is my home.ts

```js
  openProductPage(product){
    this.navCtrl.push(ProductDetailsPage, {"product": product} );
  }
```

And this is the html file home.html

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let products of moreProducts" text-wrap (click)="openProductPage(product)">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
          <img [src]="products.featured_src" />
        </ion-thumbnail>

        <h1>{{products.title}}</h1>
        <p>
          <span [innerHTML]="products.short_description.substr(0, 50) + '...'"></span>
          <span [innerHTML]="products.price_html"></span>
        </p>

         <button ion-button  icon clear item-right>
           <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
         </button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

And when I click to an product it show "undefined " in the console log
by the way I added all necessary things in the app.module.ts 
which import "..." & declarations & entryComponents

Comment: You are passing wrong variable in (click) method. That should be like (click)="openProductPage(products)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are using `products` in the `ngFor`, so you should use that variable when you call the method click

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let products of moreProducts" text-wrap (click)="openProductPage(products)">
```

Comment: If the answer works for you @MohamedAliLassoued, please can you accept it?